# iOS: upload button in WebView allows multiple images to be selected

Tags: ios, iphone, webview

I am using a WebView within an iOS app.  There is a button in my web app that uploads an image. When accessed via a computer/web, it brings up your directory to select a photo.  The problem is that when flow is done on iOS through the WebView, it opens the image picker and allows multiple images.  If I wanted to limit it to one, is that something that I would do through my HTML code so that when it's accessed in the WebView, it would limit it to 1 photo -- or is that something I would have to have written in the iOS app to control?